# Footable don't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I'm using the plugin Footable, FootablePaginate for an html table created with an ajax call but I don't know what is wrong, when document loads the table is there but there is no Footable options until I press F12, then appears the paginate from Footable but appears like this:

[image: Footable]

Footer is wrong and I put the option to show 1 row per page but when table load shows all the rows and the when I change the page appears the determinate number of pages.

Here is my table:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="footable" id="Tabla2" data-page-size="1">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <td>ID<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Revision<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Proposito<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>OpenDate<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>CloseDate<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Copias<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Estatus<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Dueño<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Modelo<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Familia<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>VS<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Estacion<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>FollowUp<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>FollowUpNumber<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td><span class="fa fa-cogs"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="TablaAlertas">
                <tr></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <div class="pagination pagination-centered"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code, I tried to add this function in the same JS file where I draw the table (ajax call) and also I tried to execute the function in the page header but I get the same result.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#Tabla2').footable();
 });
```

**EDIT:**

AJAX call:

Is basically a MySQL query (Select *) and here is the js code:

```
 success: function (data) {
        //Conversion de los datos obtenidos a un arreglo de JSON
        var aRC = JSON.parse(data.d);
        //Variable lineas que permitira dibujar la tabla HTML
        var lineas = "";
        //FOR para recorrer el arreglo
        for (var i = 0; i < aRC.length; i++) {
            //Variables que guardaran el dato obtenido en el arreglo
            var id = ("00000" + (parseInt(aRC[i].Id)));
            var zerofillid = id.substring(id.length - 5);
            //var id = aRC[i].Id;
            var num = zerofillid;
            var rev = aRC[i].Revision;
            var pur = aRC[i].Purpose;
            var open = aRC[i].Open;
            var close = aRC[i].Close;
            var copies = aRC[i].Copies;
            var status = aRC[i].Status;
            var owner = aRC[i].Owner;
            var mod = aRC[i].Model;
            var fam = aRC[i].Family;
            var vs = aRC[i].ValueStream;
            var sta = aRC[i].Station;
            var fu = aRC[i].Follow;
            var fun = aRC[i].FollowNumber;

            //Creacion de cada TR para cada dado obtenido
            lineas += '<tr id="P' + zerofillid + '" data-id="' + zerofillid + '">';
            //lineas += '<td id="P' + id + '-1">' + aRC[i].Id + '</td>'
            lineas += '<td>' + num + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-1">' + rev + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-2">' + pur + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-3">' + open + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-4">' + close + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-5">' + copies + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-6">' + status + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-7">' + owner + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-8">' + mod + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-9">' + fam + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-10">' + vs + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-11">' + sta + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-12">' + fu + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td id="P' + zerofillid + '-13">' + fun + '</td>';
            lineas += '<td>';
            //Botones de accion
            lineas += '   <span class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-edit" data-id="' + zerofillid + '"></span>';
            lineas += ' </td>';

            lineas += '</tr>';


        }
        //Id de donde se dibujara la variable lineas
        $('#TablaAlertas').html(lineas);
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

The table also works when I re-size the window

Comment: you should probably include the `ajax` code also

Comment: Have you tried this in multiple browsers? If it only starts working after you open dev tools it could be some sort of race condition or browser issue with the pages style, which the reflow caused by opening dev tools would fix.

Comment: Works in IE, but in chrome and firefox not

Comment: The table also works when I change the size of the window.